# Create a LibreOffice document with embedded macro

Tags: java, macros, libreoffice

Just as title says: I'm writing a program that should create a LibreOffice Calc document with embedded macro (and run it afterwards). I have found a way to create [empty Calc document](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/java/Spreadsheet/EuroAdaption.java) and good example of [running already embedded macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931195/running-openoffice-macro-from-java-api), but I can't figure how to insert new programmatically. Is there any API methods I've missed?

I'm writing in Java and macro is in LO Basic, doubt that matters but anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write a separate Java program (not necessarily a macro) that does the following:

1. Create an empty Calc .ods file.
2. Unzip the file.
3. Modify the XML files to [embed the macro](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language#Embedded_within_an_OpenOffice.org.27s_document).  This shows how to embed a Python macro, but Basic can be added in a similar way.
4. Zip the file.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the way I'll do it. Little sad as I hoped for more elegant way with use of Java UNO API, but this also OK.